# How to fetchAll all the columns from the database

Tags: php, database, pdo, fetch

I have a coding like this

```
        $tampilUbahVerifikator = $app['db']->prepare("
            select p.nama_pegawai, v.id_pegawai, v.id_verifikator, v.penanggung_jawab,

            rtrim(whitelist_pembayaran || decode(whitelist_pembayaran, null, null, ', ') ||
            whitelist_pemasang || decode(whitelist_pemasang, null, null, ', ') ||
            whitelist_jenis_iklan, ', ') as whitelist,

            rtrim(blacklist_pembayaran || decode(blacklist_pembayaran, null, null, ', ') ||
            blacklist_pemasang || decode(blacklist_pemasang, null, null, ', ') ||
            blacklist_jenis_iklan, ', ') as blacklist

            from verifikator v, pegawai p
            where p.id_pegawai=v.id_pegawai and v.id_verifikator = :idverifikator

            ");
        $tampilUbahVerifikator->bindValue("idverifikator", $verifikatorId);
        $tampilUbahVerifikator->execute();
        $data_ubah_ver = $tampilUbahVerifikator->fetchAll();
```

How so I can fetchAll all columns that exist in the database?
example :

```
$data['nama_pegawai'];
$data['whitelist'];
```

etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$tampilUbahVerifikator = $app['db']->prepare("
    select p.*, v.*,

    rtrim(whitelist_pembayaran || decode(whitelist_pembayaran, null, null, ', ') ||
    whitelist_pemasang || decode(whitelist_pemasang, null, null, ', ') ||
    whitelist_jenis_iklan, ', ') as whitelist,

    rtrim(blacklist_pembayaran || decode(blacklist_pembayaran, null, null, ', ') ||
    blacklist_pemasang || decode(blacklist_pemasang, null, null, ', ') ||
    blacklist_jenis_iklan, ', ') as blacklist

    from verifikator v, pegawai p
    where p.id_pegawai=v.id_pegawai and v.id_verifikator = :idverifikator

    ");
```

Note the p.* and v.* to select all from table p and v.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
$tampilUbahVerifikator->bindValue("idverifikator", $verifikatorId);
```

To

```
 $tampilUbahVerifikator->bindValue(':idverifikator', $verifikatorId);
```